# connecting to Yii framework

Tags: php, yii

So I'm having a problem with opening one project which is worked in Yii framework. I installed XAMPP, downloaded Yii's needed documentation, extracted everything where it's needed, it as said, but still it's writing this message :

"Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\radnici\framework\yii.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\radnici\index.php on line 12

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\radnici\framework\yii.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\radnici\index.php on line 12"

Heres the index.php code:

```
// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'\framework\yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

Comment: Well, is there a `framework` folder in the same directory that `index.php` is in?

Comment: yes of course, i said i did that

Comment: No, you said you "extracted everything where it's needed", yet your PHP installation is complaining that `C:\xampp\htdocs\radnici\framework\yii.php` does not exist, hence me asking if it *actually* exists. If it *does* exist then you need to make sure the file is readable by the user that XAMPP is using, but most likely (since it's Windows), everything should be default readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to install from composer?
it's the preferred way to install yii

Comment: I i'll try then I'll inform you.

Comment: or try to run `init()`

Comment: i successfully installed it from composer. Thanks